# Removed AssemblyInfo.cs from .NET6 migrated app, now the app doesn't grab the version number

Tags: c#

This app started a few years ago and I recently migrated to .NET6. After migration, I found that AssemblyInfo was still hanging around so I deleted it, now my app doesn't get the FileVersion that I have set in the project properties. I have another app that was started as a .NET5 app and it works perfectly.

This is what I use to put the "build version" on the title bar.

```
this.Text += " " + FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FileVersion;
```

Comment: FileVersionInfo provides the *unmanaged* version resource.  Which has two ways to provide a file version: a string as returned by FileVersion and a number as returned by FileMajorPart.FileMinorPart.FileBuildPart.FilePrivatePart.  Only the latter is set in a .NET6 project.

Comment: OK but what I'm saying is this. Both of my apps have this in the .csproj file: <FileVersion>2022.04.14.1251</FileVersion>

One of them displays this correctly on the tile bar using the above code and the other does not, only reports 0.0.0.0. The only difference between the two was one has been migrated over the years. I'm wondering what's wrong and how to fix it.